# jQuery animation slideLeft without text wrapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I would like to show / hide a paragraph of text using jQuery left to right.

I'm using

```
$('#text').animate({
     width: ['toggle', 'swing']
});
```

However I am seeing that the paragraph wraps as the animation is happening. And it looks ugly.

See [this js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RDsqy/) for an example of the undesired effect.

How would you recommend getting the same effect but with no wrapping? (Like `.slideUp()` / `slideDown()`)...

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `overflow: hidden` on the container, and then apply the animation to the container.

[Updated fiddle with fix here](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/RDsqy/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

CSS:

```
#wrap{
 width:200px;   
    overflow: Hidden;
}
#text{
 width:200px;  
}
```

Script:

```
setTimeout(
function(){
    $('#wrap').animate( // Changed to slide the wrap instead of the #text
        {
            width: ['toggle', 'swing']
        })
    },
1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RDsqy/2/